# Python is acting weird with math calculations, why did this happen?

Tags: python, numpy

I was bored today, so I started to write some few-minutes codes to pass the time. Anyway I wanted to see what is the functional relationship between x to the power of x and x itself, so I wrote the following codes.

```
x = np.arange(1,21,1)
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append(len(str(i**i)))
plt.plot(x,y,'b')
```

That seems quite simple and absolutely impossible to go wrong, right? There is no error indeed, but the output image is like this.

[image: Output image]

That is so strange, so I wrote the following codes to verify, `print(len(str(20**20)))` but this was normal and gave me the result of `27`.

It stands to reason that the curve of this function should soar all the way, but it has serious problems at `16` and `20`. Is this a Python problem? Why did this happen?

Comment: Why are you using `np.arange()` instead of just `list(range(1, 21)`? Does it work if you use an ordinary list?

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(y)`?

Comment: Ordinary list does work, because ordinary integers in Python do not overflow, thank you Barmar.

Answer (score 1):

Good question - the data type of the values in x are np.int64. You are overflowing 64-bits when you perform 16**16. Python's intrinsic int data type has no such limit though. So you should either cast your data as int before conversion:

```
y.append(len(str(int(i)**int(i))))
```

or define x as an int array:

```
x = list(range(1, 21))
```

Comment: That is exactly what happened, thank you Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

`np.arange()` sets dtype of `x[i]` as `int64` which overflows for large values. `list(range(1,21))` would work.

Comment: That is exactly what happened, thank you Ishan.

Comment: I couldn't understand why it was overflowing, then I realized I was misreading it as `i*i`.

Answer (score 0):

Data type in `numpy` is different than it in Python.
It gets overflowed, as it is `int` in C.

Comment: That is exactly what happened, thank you delta.